# Ordering sql query by first letter

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search, full-text-search

I am trying to order my mysql queries based on the first letter but every method I have used is restricting my search.

**Example**
MySQL table
Value
computer services
abc computer services
dynamic computer services

If I search for `computer services` I want the results to returned as:

```
**Name**
computer services
abc computer services
dynamic computer services
```

I am using mysql fullsearch text but if i use `name LIKE 'c%'` I don't the other two results e.g.

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE match('name') against('computer services*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND name LIKE 'c%';
```

This would only return

- computer services

But I want it to return:

- computer services
- abc computer services
- dynamic computer services

I am new to mysql full search text.

Comment: I don't know much about full text search (which is why I'm posting as a comment, not an answer) but I will guess try to get rid of `name LIKE 'c%'` and see what happens. This expression will only match things that begin with `c` and are followed by anything. `abc computer services` does not begin with `c` so I think that is why it doesn't get selected.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who posted. Amazing respone within minutes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an order by clause that matches the 'starts with' case first. I'm using `not like` here because the boolean returns 0 or 1 and we want to reverse that to match the starts with case first.

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE match('name') against('computer services*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY name NOT LIKE 'computer services%', name;
```